# Disk Full, Can't login

Tags: kubuntu, disk-usage, malware

I'm running Kubuntu 20.10.
I had at least some 5 GB free earlier today. Then apps started acting up. I checked in dolphin, and found I had 0 GB free. I cleared space, at least 2 GB, but it filled up again. My computer is going through the same cycle repeatedly, filling up the disk space after I clear it. I can't make out what files are being created, or how this is happening. I tried following advice from this site, such as using lsof to see if a particular process is the culprit, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Because of the sudden nature of the problem, I fear some sort of malware.

I have tried putting ClamAV, but it gives error when attempting to download definitions.

Please advise. Thanking you in advance.

Edit:
Apparently I can login to TTY.
I tried this and deleted a file from TTY, but the space cleared starts filling up again immediately.

Now I'm running 'du -h --time / | sort -rh' in case that helps.

Comment: Grab a Live USB, boot into the live session, and start making space on the storage device. If you have an external device where you can store data, then offload some of your files temporarily so that you can boot, find the problem, and resolve it 

Comment: I wouldn't assume it's malware that easily.  5 GB can go fairly quickly if certain programs are running.  Before you assume malware, you should consider if you ran an unknown file recently, connected it to an unknown network, etc.  For it to be malware, it had to get on to your computer somehow...

Comment: I did run an unknown file. I found a zip file on my computer, and looked what was inside. There was what seemed to be a windows executable. I accidentally clicked on it, when I meant to right click and see properties. It started extracting. I didn't think it ran, since I don't have wine, but I quickly deleted the zip. I thought problem over, then space started decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by checking /var/log for extensively large files.

Boot a Live-USB, mount your system volume (or the appropriate volume, where /var/log resides) and check file-sizes. If you find very large files in there, I'd suggest checking the contents with the tail command (eg. `tail -n 100 /var/log/large_file`, where -n 100 is the amount of lines of the end of the files to get output) to see whats going on in there, as opening in a normal editor may take a while and eventually fill your RAM.

If its not the log-files, another very useful tool is QDirStat: it shows how much space is in use by all the subdirs of a given starting directory. It's not installed by default, but should be in the universe repository, if I am not mistaken.

As an alternative to QDirStat, you can try `du` from a live-USB. Again, mount your affected system volume, then:
`sudo du -sh /mountpoint/of/your/system` gives you a summary (-s) in human readable format (-h) of disk usage of your folders. From there you can manually iterate down the largest folders by repeating the command and adapting the given path.

Comment: Nothing in /var/log  takes up really large amounts.

Comment: Can du provide functionality like QDirStat? I'm not in a position to install, disk space decreases by a few MB per second upon login

Comment: I see, if you dont have a live-USB with persistent storage (which allows installation of packages in live system), see the edit of my answer above.

Comment: Using du did the trick. I found out that Thunderbird turned out to be the problem. An recently added email account was taking up twice the space it took up on the server. An older version had a similar sounding bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=803843 If anybody else faces it, I also found this interesting piece: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Minimize_the_size_of_a_profile